# How to make zone/dc awareness connection to Cassandra from spark?

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spring-data, datastax-java-driver, spring-data-cassandra

I am using spark-sql 2.4.1 , spark-cassandra-connector_2.11-2.4.1.jar and java8.
While I am trying to fetch data from table I am encountering

```
java.io.IOException: Failed to write statements to keyspace1.model_vals. The
latest exception was
  An unexpected error occurred server side on cassandra-node1: com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ReadTimeoutException: Operation timed out - received only 0 responses.
```

So how to make zone/dc awareness connection to Cassandra db from spark code ?

**YML**

> existing one

```
spring:
  data:
      cassandra:
        keyspace-name: raproduct
        contact-points:
                    - cassandra-node1
                    - cassandra-node2
        port: 9042
```

> Changed to

```
spring:
  data:
      cassandra:
        connection:
          local_dc: southeast-1
        keyspace-name: raproduct
        contact-points:
                    - cassandra-node1
                    - cassandra-node2
        port: 9042
```

> Question

But it is not reflected/applied the changed "local_dc".
How to do it in spring-data ?

Answer (score 5):

Check through the [Spark Connector documentation](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/1_connecting.md) and in the [Configuration Reference - Cassandra Connection Parameters](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/reference.md#cassandra-connection-parameters). It would seem that this can be done by setting the `spark.cassandra.connection.local_dc` property in the connection configuration:

```
val conf = new SparkConf(true)
        .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "192.168.1.10")
        .set("spark.cassandra.auth.username", "flynn")            
        .set("spark.cassandra.auth.password", "reindeerFlotilla82")
        .set("spark.cassandra.connection.local_dc", "encom_west1_dc")

val sc = new SparkContext("spark://192.168.1.133:7077", "test", conf)
```

Not sure what your connection config code looks like, but try setting that `spark.cassandra.connection.local_dc` property and see where that gets you.

Comment: @BdLearner That would depend on which `LoadBalancingPolicy` Spark uses to connect to Cassandra with (under the hood).  But typically you're right, the whole idea behind setting a "local" DC, is to prevent the app from engaging in any cross-DC communication.

Comment: Yes it will only talk to the local_dc. The Connector has a special load balancing policy which only connects to nodes in the local dc.

Comment: Thanks @RussS!  I was wondering if you were going to jump in here.

Comment: There is currently no way to fall back to another DC without using a custom connection factory and load balancing policy

Comment: @BdLearner That tells the connector whether or not it should load defaults from the Java system properties.